# How to check and uncheck a checkbox in jquery based on a value in a textarea

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textarea

I have the jquery code shown below. The first time through, as I enter anything into the textarea for `#statement`, the corresponding checkbox at `#checkbox` shows on screen as checked -- perfect.

Then when once I clear the textarea for `#statement`, the corresponding checkbox at `#checkbox` shows on screen as unchecked -- so good so far.

But then as I continue to type again in the textarea for `#statement`, the corresponding checkbox at `#checkbox` **does not show** on screen as checked -- not good.

```
  $('#statement').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if ($('#statement').val() != '') $('#checkbox').attr('checked', true);
    else $('#checkbox').attr('checked', false);
  }); // end .bind()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. you just need to use prop instead of attr.
here is how

```
$('#statement').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if ($('#statement').val() != '') $('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    else $('#checkbox').removeProp('checked');
}); // end .bind()
```

Comment: on both the if and the else? @MuhammadSaifullah

Comment: I also did this `$('#checkbox').prop('checked', false)` and tested it and it works perfectly. Thanks @MuhammadSaifullah

Comment: Yes on both, always use prop and removeProp when using html properties the deal with bool.

Comment: actually the `.removeProp('checked', false)` did not work like the original `.prop('checked', false)` did so I reverted back. [in Chrome latest/stable]

Comment: Bear in mind the warning that `removeProp()` shouldn't be used if you want to use that property again; `removeProp` *removes the property itself* it doesn't just unset it.

Answer (score 2):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd suggest a slightly modified approach:

```
$('#statement').on('keyup paste input', function(){
    $('#checkbox').prop('checked', this.value.trim().length > 0);
});
```

In response to the comment, from the OP, asking for a rationale for why this might be a better approach there are two significant improvements:

- First, the use of `prop()` to both set and unset the `checked` property; this is an improvement because, reading the documentation, the jQuery team explicitly say:

> ...Do not use [`removeProp()`]to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. **This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element**. Use `.prop()` to set these properties to `false` instead.
>
> (**Emphasis** mine).

- Second, the use of `String.trim()` to remove leading, and trailing, white-space from the string and *then* comparing the length; this prevents a user bypassing the check<sup>1</sup> by entering a white-space string and thereby triggering the checking of the checkbox.

---

1. Insofar as you can be assured of *any* protection against a hostile user in your client-side scripting: remember to validate on the server as well as on the client, this is ***not optional***.

Comment: ok, thanks @DavidThomas. The answer accepted earlier works for me as I tested it. Can you modify your answer by providing rationale as to why your "slightly modified approach" might be a better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the keyup event as follows:

```
$('#statement').keyup( function(){
    if( $('#statement').val().length > 0  )
       $("#checkbox").prop('checked' , 'keyup'  );
    else
        $("#checkbox").removeProp( 'checked' );
});
```